# How do you query rows with regex that includes column values

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've got a table where identifiers(XXXXX-**065**-00) should match a division(**65**). I'd like to query all the rows that don't match.

The following SQL seems to work, but is there a better or more efficient way of doing this?

```
select id,division,identifier from table where identifier not REGEXP '.....-'+division+'-..'
```

Comment: Are the division numbers all the same length? And if they are shorter than 3 digits, should the preceding digit(s) be part of the match?

Comment: The division can be any number between 10 and 175, but they are represented in the identifier as 010 - 175 ( the identifier always has the same number of characters. )

Comment: @GMB solution ought to work for you then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat()` the regex string:

```
where identifier not regexp concat('^.{5}-', lpad(division, 3, '0'), '-..$')
```

Note that in MySQL `+` is a numeric addition (it does not do string concatenation, like in SQL Server for example).

Other remarks:

- you probably need to pad the `division` with `'0'`s so it has exactly 3 characters
- I added `^`/`$` to make the regex match on the entire string rather than do partial matching, since this seems to be what you want
- you can use quantifiers: `.{5}` stands for `.....`

Comment: Is there a way to "loosely" pad the division in the event that it's 150 instead of 050?

Comment: @HLD: `lpad(division, 3, '1')`?

Comment: `where identifier not regexp concat('^.{5}-', lpad(division, 3, '0'), '-..$')` did the trick. I think the + in the last part of the concat is redundant.